# Application getting undeployed automatically in weblogic

Tags: java, weblogic, high-availability, undeploy

We have a web application which is deployed in weblogic 10.3.6 in clustered mode.

Problem is that once is a while this application gets un-deployed by itself after/during server restart.

Is there a valid explanation of this ?

Comment: One more point, We are deploying the application through the exploded folder and not through the war as weblogic gives both the options.

Comment: Can you check the config.xml and see if your web application is still delared or not after a server restart ?

Comment: @Emmauel Collin : This is an intermittent issue and web application is currently declared after server start. Will see this we face the un-deployment next time. Thanks for pointers

Comment: I have been told that if we put a file directly in the deployment directory with the compilation errors let's say a JSP with compilation error.

Weblogic will undeploy the application.

Any idea if this is correct ?

Comment: Are you using the auto-deployment feature of weblogic server ? Otherwise, how are you deploying your application and in which mode (archive or exploded directory structure) ?

Comment: undeploying or chaging state ?

Comment: Weblogic is undeploying the application